# Finding and replacing Harvard style citations

Tags: regex

I am looking to understand a regex for that captures citations in text. It must only fine any parenthesis that contains a 4 digit number #### and a comma , (the comma may be more than 1 and not necessarily beside the number )

I want to replace the following types of text in sentences/paragraphs with a single space

(Yi et al., 2014)

(Jukić, Sharma, Nestorov, & Jukić,2015)

etc

is it possible? I will be using JavaScript replace() function to perform the replace.

I have read loads of existing citation regex's on StackOverflow that all match other bracketed text as well.  I have the following `str.replace(/(?!0000)\([^(]+\)/g," ");`  however it finds any bracketed text :/

Thank you

Comment: As shown here https://www.regextester.com/96554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching only such substrings between parentheses that contain 4-digit numbers as whole words that start with `19` or `20` (XXth and XXIst centuries):

```js
/\([^()]*\b(?:19|20)\d{2}\b[^()]*\)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jiam4a/1). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than round brackets
- `\b`  - a whole word
- `(?:19|20)`  - 19 or 20
- `\d{2}` - any two digits
- `\b`  - a whole word
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than round brackets
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, that works a treat and I think I am actually getting some understanding of this cryptic regex stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```js
var input = "text (Jukić, Sharma, Nestorov, & Jukić,2015) more text";
var output = input.replace(/\([^)]*,[^)]*?\d{4}\)/, " ");
console.log(output);
```

Explanation of the regex:

```regex
\(      match (
[^)]*   consume everything without crossing a ( until reaching
,       a comma
[^)]*?  consume all content up until the nearest
\d{4}   year
\)      )
```

Comment: good but I find it completely bewildering, your solution misses the following (Schmidt et al. 2010) - can we add the phrase 'et al' or if there is no comma (Smith 2010)

Comment: I won't edit my answer, but you can use this regex pattern: `\([^)]*(?:,|et al\.)[^)]*?\d{4}\)`

Comment: Thank you, two final tests (Smith 2000) - No comma and (Smith 2000, 2001)